# Input values based on a different column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to copy down the value from a cell above as long as the value in another column is the same and if not use a mean value of the values that exist.

Basically i want to create a time series where the value that came before should be used, unless there was no bench mark.

Example and example solution below

[image] [image]

```
Name Date Value
A 01/01/2018
A 02/01/2018
A 03/01/2018
A 04/01/2018 15
A 05/01/2018
A 06/01/2018 18
B 01/01/2018
B 02/01/2018
B 03/01/2018
B 04/01/2018
B 05/01/2018 30
B 06/01/2018
B 07/01/2018
B 08/01/2018 35
B 09/01/2018
B 10/01/2018
C 01/01/2018
C 02/01/2018
C 03/01/2018
C 04/01/2018 45
C 05/01/2018
C 06/01/2018
C 07/01/2018 53
C 08/01/2018
C 09/01/2018 48
C 10/01/2018
C 11/01/2018
C 12/01/2018
```

Comment: Can you add the example code that you have tried, with DataFrame ?

Comment: Please share data in a form where I don't have to type it in by hand as a prerequisite to helping you.

Comment: I have only managed it in excel, I have looked at .rolling and interpolate but neither do quite what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
# Calculate the mean and put it to an auxiliary column
df = df.set_index('Name')
df['Mean'] = df.groupby(df.index)['Value'].mean()

# Forward fill the gaps [.ffill() doesn't work here for some reason]
df['Value'] = df.groupby(df.index)['Value'].fillna(method='ffill')

# Fill the remaining gaps with the mean
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(df['Mean'])

# Remove the auxiliary column and the index
df = df.drop('Mean', 1).reset_index()
```

giving you the exact output you posted.